# Rails nested form edits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I am trying to figure out the whole nested form thing, and am having issues rending the form for editing.

I'm not doing this the "typical way" with a new and create action, because i'm not actually going to be saving anything. I'm just using this form to generate some tests.

Here is what I have..

model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :columns
  has_many :associations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :associations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:type].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :columns, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
  attr_accessible :name, :associations_attributes, :columns_attributes
end
```

column.rb

```
class Column < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  attr_accessible :db_index, :mass_assign, :max_length, :min_length, :name, :required,     :unique, :columns_attributes

  validates :name, :presence => true

end
```

generator_controller.rb

```
  def model
    if params['submit']
      @model = Model.new(params[:model])
      @model.columns.build

    else
      @model = Model.new
      3.times { @model.columns.build }
    end

    render 'generator/model'
  end
```

form view

```
<%= nested_form_for(@model, :url => '/model', :html => {:style => 'width:100%;'}) do |f| %>
          <%= flash_helper() %>
          <h3>Model Name</h3>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>

          <h3>Add Table Columns</h3>

          <div id="columns">
            <% f.fields_for :columns do |builder| %>
                <div class="float_left column">
                  <%= builder.label :name %>
                  <br>
                  <%= builder.text_field :name, :size => 20 %>
            </div>
            <div class="float_left column">
              <%= builder.label :mass_assign %>
              <br>
              <%= builder.check_box :mass_assign %>
            </div>
            <div class="float_left column">
              <%= builder.label :required %>
              <br>
              <%= builder.check_box :required %>
            </div>
            <div class="float_left column">
              <%= builder.label :unique %>
              <br>
              <%= builder.check_box :unique %>
            </div>

            <div class="float_left column">
              <%= builder.label :db_index %>
              <br>
              <%= builder.check_box :db_index %>
            </div>
            <div class="float_left column">
              <br>
              <%= image_tag "delete-icon24x24.png", :class => "btnDel clickable" %>
            </div>
            <br class="clear_float">
        <% end %>
        <%= f.link_to_add image_tag('add-icon.png'), :columns %>

      </div>

      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">

      <p>
        <%= @results %>
      </p>

  <% end %>
```

So the problem is, the form when new is not displaying the columns that "3.times { @model.columns.build }" is supposed to do. Also, when I submit the form, I need to figure out why it is getting rid of all of those nested attributes that were added. So each time I submit the form, and it renders the form again, all the attributes are gone. (The "model" attributes are still there, but the "column" attributes reset each time)

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am embarrassed to even admit this, but hopefully it will help someone else with one more thing to check if they have the same problem.

```
<% f.fields_for :columns do |builder| %>
```

changed to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :columns do |builder| %>
```

Yeah.. can't believe I did that...

Comment: I was having the same problem for days and couldnt figure out the problem, turned out I also made this embaressing mistake.. thanks for posting this!